# How do you change the text cursor in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I saw this video and i wanted to know how i could make the IBeam cursor have those lines come out of it in Visual Studio?  thanks :)[image of what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWfur.png)

Comment: That is just a Windows feature. If you want a Control to have a specific Cursor, you can set the Cursor property of that Control from the interface of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to install an extension in Visual Studio.
Try to download and install one of these:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomasRestrepo.Viasfora

I hope it been useful for you.

Comment: ok thanks, i was using vs community, guess ill switch to vs code